# Header function no work properly with session destroy in php

Tags: php

I am trying to go index page after log out by my below code but it takes me that page which page contains log out code.

**Log out page calling by this code**

```
<a href="logout.php">
    <span class="gly glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span>Log Out
</a>
```

**Log out code**

```
session_start();
session_destroy();
header('location : index.php');
```

After logout click it's take me to "http://localhost/check/logout.php" page,

Comment: can u show the php code written on index.php it seems, your code on index.php  has some redirection based on session, thats why its redirecting to logout.php

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your file structure, where you have a folder (or rewrite) where logout.php is located you are redirected to that page due to your anchor. Add a slash "/" before logout.php in your anchor to go to localhost/logout.php.

Incase the file is resolved (your question is a little vague) and you are not being redirected this is due to the header you defined. You should uppercase the first letter of location to do a propper redirect.

```
 header('Location: index.php');
```

Comment: At same folder folder stay logout.php, index.php, nav.php . From my nav.php file i linked logout.php and logout.php destroy my session takes me in logout.php page but i want to go index.php .

Comment: You should be more specific because i dont understand a word your saying. Do you have errors? when opening logout.php are you redirected? Do you have more examples of code or a small overview of your file structure? We cant help you if you dont share critical information about your application where the problem persists.

Comment: From navigation i linked logout.php and by logout.php i want to destroy session and redirected to index.php . But it takes/gives me a blank page which url is localhost/myfoldername/logout.php. And i try with capital 'L' in header location, but same result came.

Comment: White pages ussaly means you have errors. Enable error reporting and set display errors to be visible to debug from there. Also check your log files dor errors.. If you cant find solution copy the errors here.

Comment: It no show any error but after using location in " " it working. Can you explain why happen it?

Comment: Yet again i dont understand your question. For brevity take a look at the following page http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php im glad your problem is solved now.